# Python - Sort nested dictionary by the second item in the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```py
{'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'zzz':['zzz', 3]}
```

I want to sort the dictionary by the second item in the value of each key from big to small, so the result I want is like this:

```py
{'zzz':['zzz', 3], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'xxx':['xxx', 0]}
```

Is there any way to do that? Thank you! Note that there might be dictionary items that have the same values

Comment: Even that dictionaries remain in insertion order in the newest Python version does not make them a great structure for sorted data.

Comment: @Brian Zheng - Which Python version are you currently using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python versions were the dicts are ordered (`CPython3.6`m `Python3.7+`) use `sorted` with reverse activated and a custom `key`:

```
>>> d = {'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'zzz':['zzz', 3]}
>>> d = dict(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
>>> d
{'zzz': ['zzz', 3], 'yyy': ['yyy', 2], 'xxx': ['xxx', 0]}
```

If not (`Python3.5` or lower), use `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'zzz':['zzz', 3]}
>>> d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
>>> d
OrderedDict([('zzz', ['zzz', 3]), ('yyy', ['yyy', 2]), ('xxx', ['xxx', 0])])
```

Comment: You should point out that this is Python 3.7 and 3.6 (non official) only.

Comment: @KlausD., yeah, I did not know by heart so I was checking it, thanks for helping on that :D

Answer (score 0):

`dicts` in Python are *sorted by insertion order* (for Python >= 3.7), so they cannot really be sorted in the same sense that a `list` can. If you want sortability, you should use a different container.

Nevertheless, for Python >= 3.7 (though it will work in CPython 3.6), you can create a new dictionary from a sorted `list` of `tuples` built from the original `dict`:

```
data = {'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'zzz':['zzz', 3]}
result = dict(sorted(data.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda p: p[1][1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
>>> d = {'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 2], 'zzz':['zzz', 3]}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1], reverse=True)
[('zzz', ['zzz', 3]), ('yyy', ['yyy', 2]), ('xxx', ['xxx', 0])]
```

Comment: Although your code works, Just pasting code without any explanation will earn you downvotes!  Keep that in mind from next time :)

Answer (score -1):

my Friend you can use sorted method:

try this:

```
x  = {'xxx':['xxx', 0], 'yyy':['yyy', 3], 'zzz':['zzz', 2],'aaa':['aaa',1]}

newlist=sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1], reverse=True)
print (newlist)
```

output:

```
[('yyy', ['yyy', 3]), ('zzz', ['zzz', 2]), ('aaa', ['aaa', 1]), ('xxx', ['xxx', 0])]
```

newlist type is list.

if you want dictionary simple use dict() as :

newlist= `dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1], reverse=True))`

output :`{'yyy': ['yyy', 3], 'zzz': ['zzz', 2], 'aaa': ['aaa', 1], 'xxx': ['xxx', 0]}`

hope this help